# PowerApps - Who can create powerapps,

Tags: powerapp

I can't find any good documents that can answer these questions

1. Who can create powerapps?
2. If a user create powerapps and publish it and if that user leaves the company can the tenant admin recover the powerapps?
3. Is SharePoint powerapps (canvas apps) different than if you were to create powerapps from the make.powerapps.com
4. Can anyone interact with a published powerapps? Do they need to have license as well?
5. Is there any good governance template regarding powerapps?
6. Is there any good template when business unit is requesting for new powerapps development.

Please help me understand these question as I have a major presentation in 1 day. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below answers for each point in your question, Hope it will answer your question.

1. User with "Environment Maker" role can create the power apps and
   share it with others in organizations.
2. For Deployment you can use DevOps or Service Account to deploy
   the PowerApps in different environments.
3. Using "Power Platform solution" option you can easily move apps
   ,flows and other artifact from one environment to another.
4. User with permission level of "Basic User" can use app but they
   require license.
5. Yes "COE open source solutions" are available that you can
   install and use it for governance and also DLP Policy.
6. Portal itself have multiple template and sample available that
   you can use it.

Reference

1. [Roles in PowerApps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/database-security)
2. [COE Starter Kit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/guidance/coe/starter-kit)

Please mark as answer if you are satisfied.